# nginx on Debian 8 downloading INI file

Tags: linux, nginx, centos

I want to redirect a specific sub domain to directory in nginx and I have some `.ini` files and i want to read them directly from browser, but instead of print the content, is downloading. How can i fix that?

My current default inside "`/etc/nginx/sites-available/`"

```
server {
    listen 80;  
    server_name subdomain.example.net;
    root /usr/share/patches/;
    location /usr/share/patches/ {
        root /usr/share/patches/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add details what is the exact URL you are trying to access with your browser, and where exactly is the file on your filesystem.

Comment: I already fix the problem, i install apache2.

Comment: It is better in the long run to use nginx and learn its configuration properly.

Answer (score 3):

`nginx` uses the file extension to determine the content type. The browser uses the content type to decide whether to display the content or download it. You can override this behaviour and force the content to be interpreted as `text/plain` or `text/html` by clearing the `types` block and adding a default type. For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;  
    server_name subdomain.example.net;

    root /usr/share/patches;
    location / {
        types {}
        default_type text/plain;
    }
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types) for details.

Comment: Hello! I added this, but still downloading (i restarted nginx)

Comment: I suspect your `location` block is being ignored. You seem to be using a pathname instead of a URI for the value of the `location`. Unless your files are stored at `/usr/share/patches/usr/share/patches/`. Your `location` block should probably be `location /`.

Comment: I use your code and change the values, but still downloading (I restarted nginx). If doesn't work, i'll change to Apache, i never had problem, people say to me use nginx (they say that is better) but i have so much problems with nginx. I don't know. Do you nave any idea why still downloading the files?

Comment: The decision to download a file is made by the browser and not `nginx`. But check the `Content-Type` that your browser sees - it will indicate if you have configured the correct server and location.